(C# )OpenDoc6 isn't opening SolidWorks .part files that are resolved
From a assembly file I get a Component2 string that, after some treatments, I try to open each file of this string, execute some tasks and than close it.
When the program calls the method OpenDoc6, SolidWorks looks like execute a opening command, but don't open any part.
I Would like to open and treat each file of a Component2 string.
Observation:
-If the children components are lighweith inside the assembly, the script works right, but if they are resolved, doesn't work;
-If I try to open any other file that is not in the assembly, it works too
Things that I tryed:
-Use Opendoc7, but i couldn't open any file with this method, not even parts that aren't in the assembly;
The part of the code:
foreach (Component2 filePath in objChildrenListNoDupes)
                    {
                        //****Still couldn't open each file...*********//
                        fileExtension = filePath.GetPathName().Split('.')[filePath.GetPathName().Split('.').Length-1].ToUpper();
                        MessageBox.Show("Path: " + filePath.GetPathName().Replace("\\", "/") + 
                            "\nExtension: " + fileExtension + 
                            "\nIts supression state is: " + filePath.GetSuppression2());
                        //To open the file, I need to send what type of file it is:
                        //1 - Part
                        //2 - Assembly
                        //3 - Drawing
                        switch (fileExtension){
                            case "SLDPRT":
                                intFileExtension = 1;
                                break;
                            case "SLDASM":
                                intFileExtension = 2;
                                break;
                            case "SLDDRW":
                                intFileExtension = 3;
                                break;
                        }
                        //The second argument could be a 3 to open just the drawings
                        swApp.OpenDoc6(filePath.GetPathName().Replace("\\", "/"), 1, (int)swOpenDocOptions_e.swOpenDocOptions_LoadLightweight, "", ref errors, ref warnings);
                    }


It won't open because it's already "open" in memory. You'll want to use ISldworks.ActivateDoc3 to open it within the UI.  https://help.solidworks.com/2020/english/api/sldworksapi/solidworks.interop.sldworks~solidworks.interop.sldworks.isldworks~activatedoc3.html
